# count closest subset among uniformly distributed points on the plane

Tags: probability

Let $G$ be a set of $p$ points uniformly distributed in a square $S$. Let us take a set $F \subset S$ of $f$ points inside the square and denote by $U_{\varepsilon}(F)$ its Euclidean $\varepsilon$-vicinity (which is a union of $f$ disks of radii $\varepsilon$ for small enough $\varepsilon$). Let us now allow all translation+rotations of $U_{\varepsilon}$ and denote them by $R(U_{\varepsilon})$, where $R$ is some translation+rotation. We will say that we found a "good" subset $F$ of $f$ points from $G$ if some $R(U_{\varepsilon})$ contains $F$ in such a way that every its small $\varepsilon$-disk contains exactly one point from $F$.

Question: How many disjoint "good" subsets can we find on average? The variance of this number?